# How do I list certain variables in the checkpoint?

Tags: variables, tensorflow, state

I am working with autoencoders. My checkpoint contains the complete state of the network (i.e. the encoder, decoder, optimizer, etc). I want to fool around with the encodings. Therefore, I would only need the decoder part of the network in my evaluation mode.

How can I read only a few specific variables from the existing checkpoint, so that I can reuse their values in another model?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's `list_variables` method in [checkpoint_utils.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/00700f00fdf71baec1342d1afd7849e16fbd2a33/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/framework/checkpoint_utils.py) which lets you see all saved variables.

However, for your use-case, it may be easier to restore with a `Saver`. If you know the names of the variables when you saved the checkpoint, you can create a new saver, and tell it to initialize those names into new `Variable` objects (possibly with different names). This is used in CIFAR example to select a restore a [subset of variables](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d42facc3cc9611f0c9722c81551a7404a0bd3f6b/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_eval.py#L134). See [Choosing which Variables to Save and Restore](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/variables/index.html#choosing-which-variables-to-save-and-restore) in the Howto

Comment: Note that `list_variables` is now accessible in `tf.train` (since TF 1.3).

Answer (score 6):

You can view the saved variables in .ckpt file using,

```
import tensorflow as tf

variables_in_checkpoint = tf.train.list_variables('path.ckpt')

print("Variables found in checkpoint file",variables_in_checkpoint)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way, that would print all checkpoint tensors (or just one, if specified) along with their content:

```
from tensorflow.python.tools import inspect_checkpoint as inch
inch.print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file('path/to/ckpt', '', True)
"""
Args:
  file_name: Name of the checkpoint file.
  tensor_name: Name of the tensor in the checkpoint file to print.
  all_tensors: Boolean indicating whether to print all tensors.
"""
```

It will always print the content of the tensor.

And, while we are at it, here is how to use `checkpoint_utils.py` (suggested by the previous answer):

```
from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.framework import checkpoint_utils

var_list = checkpoint_utils.list_variables('./')
for v in var_list:
    print(v)
```

Comment: `checkpoint_utils` has been moved since TF 2.x.  I import it by  

`from tensorflow.python.training import checkpoint_utils`