# Key not found in checkpoint Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on building a typing assistant using deep learning. I already have a pre-trained model which I am trying to load to predict the next few words.

Although the code works on the server(where the model has been trained), when I try to load the model on the system and try to predict. It is producing the this error.

> tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key dq4st0/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/biases not found in checkpoint

The code for predictions is as follows

```
def text_output(args, bucket):
    gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=args['gpu_mem'])

    with open(os.path.join(args['save_dir'], str(bucket)+'/config.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        saved_args = cPickle.load(f)
    with open(os.path.join(args['save_dir'], str(bucket)+'/words_vocab.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
        words, vocab = cPickle.load(f)
    model = Model(saved_args, bucket, True)
    sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session =sess)
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())

    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(args['save_dir']+"/"+str(bucket))

    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)

    return args,model,words,vocab, sess
```

Comment: Is tensorflow version the same? `RNNCell` is rewritten pretty often, e.g. see [this change](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/e8482ab23bd0fce5c2941f6a190158bca2610a35) between 1.1 and 1.2. What's the list of variables [saved into a checkpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944238/tensorflow-list-variables-in-the-checkpoint)?

Answer (score 4):

A possible problem is that the variable names in your code do not match the keys in the checkpoint file.

My suggestion is to check the variable names as follows:

1. get the variable names in your code:

   ```
   var_name_list = [v.name for v in tf.trainable_variables()]
   ```
2. get the keys in checkpoint file:

   ```
   from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

   reader = pywrap_tensorflow.NewCheckpointReader(ckpt_path)
   var_to_shape_map = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()
   ```

You can compare them to check whether the `dq4st0/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/biases` exists in your ckpt file.